# Building Android app in Ubuntu 16 Docker Container ( Oracle JDK 8 & MVN)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

Below stacktrace is for android build. And execution is failed for command: `./gradlew -qq assembleStandardDebug assembleStandardDebugAndroidTest`

To verify Gradle is fine tried command `./gradlew tasks" but it completed successfully`

Then started debugging for dependency issues but didn't get much stacktrace. This is the first time I am trying to build an android project and also trying on docker container. If anyone have idea please let me know.

> 15:08:19  ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not
>   match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3
>   used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version
>   4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for
>   parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1
>   ui/utils/UiHelper.java:202: warning: Application namespace for
>   attribute app:imageSrc will be ignored. 15:08:19      public static
>   void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String image) { 15:08:19
>   ^ 15:08:25  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   15:08:25  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   15:08:25  Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   15:08:25  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 15:08:25 
>   1 warning 15:10:17   15:10:17  FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception. 15:10:17   15:10:17  * What went wrong: 15:10:17  Execution
>   failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileStandardDebugAndroidTest'.
>   15:10:17  > Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:standardDebugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'. 15:10:17     > Failed
>   to transform artifact 'cucumber-java.jar
>   (io.cucumber:cucumber-java:3.0.2)' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar,
>   org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}. 15:10:17        > Execution failed for
>   JetifyTransform:
>   /root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/3.0.2/6b1790c541528f8b3a47/cucumber-java-3.0.2.jar.
>   15:10:17           > Failed to transform
>   '/root/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.cucumber/cucumber-java/3.0.2/6b1790c541528f8b3a47/cucumber-java-3.0.2.jar'
>   using Jetifier. Reason: Malformed input or input contains unmappable
>   characters: cucumber/api/java/sk/Ataktie?.class. (Run with
>   --stacktrace for more details.) 15:10:17   15:10:17  * Try: 15:10:17  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
>   insights.

Comment: ` Reason: Malformed input or input contains unmappable characters: cucumber/api/java/sk/Ataktie?.class`

Comment: Your build, os, or file system doesn't support unicode file names. Try excluding those packages.